# WPML. After string translation some strings are still displayed in English

Tags: wordpress, string, translation, wpml

I came across the following problem. I use Wordpress with WPML for English and Lithuanian languages and Woocommerce. Although I translated all the necessary strings with String Translation, some of them are still displayed in English. What can be the problem?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: You need to know if the text displayed were passed through the translation functions in the first place. if they are raw text, then you need to figure out solutions for example maybe hook into the functions filters/actions and use translation functions.

Comment: You would be better off posting to the WPML forum. https://wpml.org/forums/forum/english-support/

Comment: Nate Beers, I don't know how to register on wpml.org. I found only the login form. https://wpml.org/account/

Comment: TurtleTread, if I understood you in a proper way, all the strings look like __("string", "woocommerce"). The problem is I'm a newbie in this sphere and the code is not mine (the senior's).